# Как вывести имя файла используя модуль pysvn под python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скрипт выводить номер ревизии, имя автора, коммит.
Как еще вывести имя файла, необходимо для будушего поиска по имени файла за определенный интервал ревизий?

есть поле `copyfrom_path`, но я не пойму как к нему получить доступ?

```
log returns a list of log entries; each log entry is a dictionary. The dictionary contains:

author - string - the name of the author who committed the revision
date - float time - the date of the commit
message - string - the text of the log message for the commit
revision - pysvn.Revision - the revision of the commit
changed_paths - list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains:
   path - string - the path in the repository
   action - string
   copyfrom_path - string - if copied, the original path, else None
   copyfrom_revision - pysvn.Revision - if copied, the revision of the original, else None
```

Код:

```
import pysvn

url = 'http://svn.code'
start_rev = 100
end_rev = 138
client = pysvn.Client()
revision_start = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, start_rev)
revision_end = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, end_rev)

for log in client.log(url, revision_start, revision_end):
    print(log.revision.number, log["author"], log["message"])
```

Answer (score 0):

> changed_paths - list of dictionaries.

Соответственно, просто перебираете вложенные в список словари ещё одним циклом:

```py
for log in client.log(url, revision_start, revision_end):
    print(log.revision.number, log["author"], log["message"])
    for chg_path in log["changed_paths"]:
        print(chg_path["copyfrom_path"])
```